# How to remove windows-like border from window in TideSdk application?

Tags: javascript, api, tidesdk

How to remove windows-like border from window in TideSdk application?
I don't find solution in the API...
[Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw8BB.jpg)
Sorry for bad English. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something that you configure in your tiapp.xml file.
In the window element, insert a chrome element with the value false. For example:

```
<window>
  <id>initial</id>
  <title>My Great App</title>
  <url>app://index.html</url>
  <width>700</width>
  <height>500</height>
  <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
  <chrome>false</chrome>
</window>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes! That helps!
Just adding in your tiapp.xml string:
`<transparent-background>true</transparent-background>`
Thanks! Please, add it in your answer.

Comment: Thx! I've been looking for it for a long time! AND I am wondering where you found it out. I cannot find this in documentation of tideSDK.